# Elasticsearch error curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused but localhost:9200 works on browser

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to connect Elasticsearch 5.5.2 to a Django 2 project following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04) :

When running : `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'` on terminal, I got this error : `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused` while `localhost:9200` works very well on my browser.

Here is an overview of my elasticsearch.yml file :

```
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true

# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

`/var/log/elasticsearch/` is empty.

Please what's wrong with curl ?

Comment: Everything seems in order... Can you try `http://127.0.0.1:9200`? Your browser might be doing some localhost resolving for you that might not be in your `/etc/hosts` or something.

Comment: Can you also do a `sudo netstat -anp | grep 9200` to verify it's listening on the box you're trying to curl from?

Comment: Trying `http://127.0.0.1:9200` does nothing. `sudo netstat -anp | grep 9200` displays nothing :(

Comment: Ok, then it looks like you're trying to curl from a different box then. Do you have anything running in a VM? Docker container? What do you get when you go to it in your browser?

Comment: I use virtualenv and ubuntu 16.04 with vagrant. When I go in browser I get `{
  "name" : "Payback",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "cXwea1mHQyeQrUCTF2lVJg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.4.6",
    "build_hash" : "5376dca9f70f3abef96a77f4bb22720ace8240fd",
    "build_timestamp" : "2017-07-18T12:17:44Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
} `

Comment: `/var/log/elasticsearch/` doesn't exist. I installed elasticsearch with python (pip)

Comment: Try visiting `http://localhost:9200/_nodes` in your browser. Then visit `http://localhost:9200/_nodes/{node_name}` based on the nodes returned. That should give you info about the node that's running. _Then_, check the IP of the box you're trying to curl from using `ifconfig -a`. I would venture a guess the IP addresses aren't the same.

Comment: Here is the the first lines of `http://localhost:9200/_nodes/`: `{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","nodes":{"hSQhDjeHQFqx0FJf1iTwkQ":{"name":"Payback","transport_address":"10.0.2.15:9300","host":"10.0.2.15","ip":"10.0.2.15","version":"2.4.6","build":"5376dca","http_address":"10.0.2.15:9200","settings":{"pidfile":"/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid","cluster":{"name":"elasticsearch"}`

Comment: the ip while doing `ifconfig -a` is : `10.0.2.15`. Need other information ?

Comment: Can you add `-4` to your curl command to force IPv4? After that I'm running out of ideas here...

Comment: Still get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

Comment: could you post the output of sudo service elasticsearch status ?

Comment: Here is the beginning of what I have : `elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-02-21 06:27:04 UTC; 9h ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 1691 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

Comment: Next lines : `Feb 21 06:27:04 ubuntu-xenial elasticsearch[1691]: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000008a660000, 1973026816, 0) failed; error='Cann
Feb 21 06:27:04 ubuntu-xenial elasticsearch[1691]: #
Feb 21 06:27:04 ubuntu-xenial elasticsearch[1691]: # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Feb 21 06:27:04 ubuntu-xenial elasticsearch[1691]: # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1973026816 bytes for committing reserved memory.` and so on...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok eureka!, You have a java heap space error. Look at that error:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue
```

You can increase/decrease - i don't know if the problem appears because your machine has too few RAM and es could not start, or you had allocated too few ram to es - the space dedicated to elastic in java virtual machine editing this file `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`
 To allocate 2 GB of RAM, you should change:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

 -Xms2g
 -Xmx2g
```

Then you have to restart the service

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

And try again with curl

Comment: `/etc/elasticsearch/` doesn't exist ! I've installed elasticsearch with `pip install elasticsearch==5.5.2`

Comment: ok you have installed python library to manage query on elasticsearch. But you have installed also elasticsearch package  - deb or tar.gz -on localhost because you have active an elasticsearch service - it responds on sudo service elasticsearch status and on http://localhost:9200/_nodes/ and you can visualize localhost:9200 on browser. ES python library is not ES DB!  one is high level client library, and the other one is ES server.

Comment: the machine that doesn't have/etc/elasticsearch is the same that responds to you typing sudo service elasticsearch status?

Comment: Yep, I work with vagrant where I've created a ubuntu virtualen

Comment: Ah ok. I don't know how ubuntu virtualen works. Probably the paths are different on a virtualenv. And I can't help you for that, sorry

Comment: I have another idea.. where is your elasticsearch.yml? jvm.options is in the same folder

Comment: I just found out that Elasticsearch isn't installed. But it's very weird because `http://localhost:9200/` continue to work and display stuffs on my windows browser while I've shut down vagrant

Comment: Restarting my computer and doing your method made everything work. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem is with java version, i installed open-jdk 11 previously. Thats creating the issue while starting the service. I changed it open-jdk 8 and it started working

```
curl localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "My First Node",
  "cluster_name" : "mycluster1",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.1",
    "build_hash" : "bd980929010aef404e7cb0843e61d0665269fc39",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-04-04T12:25:05Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but not the same cause as answered by Lupanoide. Adding my findings for others.

I was also getting connection refused on ip:9200 but localhost:9200 was working. When i tried "network.host : 0.0.0.0" the service would not start. I changed the value to "http.host" as seen below and that allowed the service to start and be called via ip.

**/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml**

```
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
http.host: 192.168.1.199
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
```

Before:

```
[root@Loki-03 ~]# curl localhost:9200
    "name" : "Loki-03"

[root@Loki-03 ~]# curl 192.168.1.199:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.199 port 9200: Connection refused
```

After:

```
[root@Loki-03 ~]# systemctl restart elasticsearch.service 
[root@Loki-03 ~]# curl 192.168.1.199:9200
    {
      "name" : "Loki-03",
```

Hope this helps.
Also, i'm running:

```
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.4.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "22e1767283e61a198cb4db791ea66e3f11ab9910",
    "build_date" : "2019-09-27T08:36:48.569419Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.2.0",
```